# Запуск уведомления через AlarmManager

Tags: android, android-alarm-manager

Пытался реализовать уведомление, которое каждую неделю показывает уведомление, но оно не работает.

```
alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, intent, 0);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 1);

    long timeToStart = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
    if(System.currentTimeMillis() < timeToStart){
        timeToStart += 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // one day
    }
    alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeToStart, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);
```

Вообщем хочу реализовать уведомление, например каждый день в 12 часов дня, помогите это сделать.

Comment: Почитайте про JobScheduler

Comment: @SviatVolkov не совсем то что нужно JobScheduler для  Android 5.0 (API 21) и выше , а мне нужно что работало на API 16

Answer (score 3):

Вот код для запуска **AlarmManager**, каждый день в *12 часов*, который в свою очередь будет запускать ваш ресивер.

```
Calendar notifyTime = DateHelper.getTodayCalendarWithoutTime();
notifyTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
notifyTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
notifyTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, notifyTime.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

Внутри ресивера проверяете условия запуска уведомления (нужно ли вообще запускать) и запускаете нужное уведомление или несколько уведомлений, в зависимости от ситуации.

```
public class NotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (reminder != null) {
            // Запускаем уведомление
            MyNotification.notify(context, message, number);
        }
    }
}
```

Сами уведомления лучше хранить отдельно и рекомендую в **Android Studio** добавлять их через *правую кнопку* мыши - **UI Component** / **Notification**. Там очень правильные шаблоны для разных типов уведомлений с подробными комментариями.

Comment: Извините, А есть более подобная информация?

Answer (score 2):

У версиях АПИ 26 и выше, требует установку chanel. Предлагаю такой выход из ситуации:

```
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
                    new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.pict01)
                            .setContentTitle(Title)
                            .setContentText(MainText)
                            //.setLargeIcon(picture);
                            .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

                CharSequence channelName = "c_name";
                int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW;
                NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel("3260", channelName, importance);
                notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
                notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
                notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
                notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
                builder.setChannelId(notificationChannel.getId());
            }

            Notification notification = builder.build();
            notificationManager.notify(a, notification);
```

Comment: А что за символ "а" в аргументе, на последней строчке?

Comment: @СергейБеляков notification id