# Как отправлять уведомления каждые 10 минут даже если приложение свайпнули из вкладок?

Tags: java, android, таймер, уведомления, вкладки

Моя программа должна отправлять уведомление каждые 10 минут даже если ее свайпнули из вкладок. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Запуск уведомления через AlarmManager](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/736388/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-alarmmanager)

Comment: @ВасяВоронцов Там немного не то. Как отправлять уведомления каждые 10 минут? Пришлите пожадуйста код

Comment: @edcft Возможно вы имеете ввиду Firebase? Могу дать пример как сделать push-notifications через Firebase, по расписанию. Либо без него? Уточните пожалуйста.

Comment: @Sh4rx Уточняю: у меня есть прога для изучения английского. Она должна напоминать о себе каждые 10 минут с помощью уведомлений(желательно со звуком, системным). Уведомление может быть необязательно push. При закрытии моей программы должен начинаться таймер 10 мин, когда проходит 10 мин показывается уведомление и таймер стартует снова, и так пока пользователь не запустит программу, при запуске таймер должен сбрасываться до следующего закрытия моей программы. Фуух... уточнил. Мою задачу можно реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку тема довольно обширная, для её понимания я подобрал для вас список статей и ресурсов с примерами которые помогут вам разобраться.

[Официальная документация](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications?hl=ru)

[startandroid.ru Уроки 184-190](https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom.html)

http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/notification.php

[Пример готового приложения на Java](https://github.com/google-developer-training/android-fundamentals-apps-v2/tree/master/NotifyMe)

[Пошаговая реализация на Java](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-training-notifications/index.html#0)

[Push-notifications](https://dimlix.com/notifications-android/)

Comment: Боюсь что составит... Я начал программировать 2 недели назад и неочень понимаю все эти сервисы и alarmmanager-ы, поэтому прошу прислать мне код который подойдет в моем случае. Помогите пожалуйста)

Comment: И к тому же там код на котлине, а мне нужно java

Comment: @edcft  Я изменил ответ, попробуйте посмотреть данные варианты. Если у вас возникнут затруднения с отдельным функционалом попробую помочь объяснить вам.

Comment: Я немного разобрался в службах. Получается что мне нужна служба, которая при запуске будет ждать 10 мин, а потом отправлять уведомление. Отсчет я делаю так `TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(10);`Только вот вопрос: как после отправки уведомления опять начать этот отсчет?

Comment: @edcft Немного не понял вопроса. Мне бы код посмотреть, как у вас реализовано это. Кстати, не обязательно TimeUnit, можно записать в  int/long в мс. Либо создать  enum с нужными значениями и внутренними методами. В андроиде есть для отсчета удобный и простой в использовании счетчик. 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer 
Попробуйте использовать его, я думаю он облегчит вам задачу. Только учитывайте что на вход он принимает мс.

Comment: Методы у него очень простые, и привязаны к каждому отдельному объекту таймера который вы создаете.
start() - запустить отсчет
cancel() - отменить отсчет.
onFinish() - коллбек вызова после окончания отсчета
onTick(long millisUntilFinished) - используем для реализации какой-то логики
Либо можно так же написать свою реализацию, как пример
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8858608/13730354

Comment: код не помещается в коментарие поэтому вот [ссылка на код в гугл документах](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1e2dAJFSg2M2LXgWRtSXK3S6Lfk4FJB-rcEk2ivyQbM8/edit?usp=sharing).  Я поставил доступ коментатора чтобы вы могли предложить там правки. Так вот вопрос: как после отправки уведомления опять засекти 10 минут и опять показать уведомление?

Comment: @edcft а дискорд есть? или хотя бы телеграм?

Comment: Ни того ни другого нет, а зачем вам? Вам неудобно в гугл документах?

Comment: Если вы волнуетесь что я увижу там вашу почту вы можете открыть доккумент во вкладке инкогнито, тогда я не увижу вашу почту.

Comment: Или возможно вы пишите с телефона и не хотите устанавливать гугл док?

Comment: Я угадал причину?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109621/discussion-between-sh4rx-and-edcft).